# I want to display a textbox when I click on a particular option of a radio button in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, textbox, radio-button, display

I have a radio button with 2 options. It goes like

```
      <td>City : </td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="r_city" value="Same" checked="checked" />Same</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="r_city" value="Different" />Different</td>
      <td>textbox here</td>
```

I want to display a textbox when i click "Different".

Its a JSP page. Thanks.

Comment: Add more HTML to make it clear. Where is your `textbox` which you want to display?

Comment: Updated. I want that textbox to be displayed only when i click "Different" it should not be visible otherwise.

Comment: Ok, I have answered your question. Was busy when you changed your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be nice to know which javascript framework you use.

With vanilla javascript this is a simple way by adding and removing hidden class on click event simply because that's most likely the only way to guaranty browser compatibility.

https://plnkr.co/edit/e9Jet9kd3f278uROO5R0?p=preview

```
// js
window.onload = () => {
  var rad2 = document.getElementById('r2');
  var rad1 = document.getElementById('r1');
  var input = document.getElementById('myInput');
  rad2.addEventListener("click", function(){
    input.classList.remove('hidden');
  });
  rad1.addEventListener("click", function(){
    input.classList.add('hidden');
  });
}


// html
<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
<td>City : </td>
<td><input type="radio" name="r_city" id="r1" value="Same" checked="checked" /></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="r_city" id="r2" value="Different" /></td>
<td><input id="myInput" class="hidden"/></td>

// css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, if you want to again hide it just use .hide() function

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>City : </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="r_city" value="Same" checked="checked"/>Same</td>
    <td><input type="radio" id="testChecked" name="r_city" value="Different" />Different</td>
    <td class="show-this" style="display:none">textbox here</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
    $('#testChecked').click(function(){
      if ($(this).is(':checked'))
      {
        $('.show-this').show();
      }
  });
</script>
```

Make sure to add jQuery***

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do. If you are using a common class for the textbox inside `<td>` then you can use the class selector instead of `input[type="text"]`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
    var textBox = $(this).closest('tr').find('td input[type="text"]');
    if($(this).val() === 'Different'){
      $(textBox).show();
    } else {
      $(textBox).hide();
    }
  });

});
```

```css
td input[type='text'] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
      <td>City : </td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="r_city" value="Same" checked="checked" />Same</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="r_city" value="Different" />Different</td>
      <td><input type='text' /></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>City : </td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="r_city1" value="Same" checked="checked" />Same</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="r_city1" value="Different" />Different</td>
      <td><input type='text' /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```